# unable to run nodejs child_process on amazon ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mongoose, child-process

I am running nodejs child_process function spawn() to do mongoexport. I have passed all the necessary fields to the command and it is working fine on my local machine. Below is the function code

```
userDetailsChild = spawn('mongoexport', ['--username',username,'--
password',password,'--db',db,'--collection','users','--type', 'csv', 
'--fields', 'userId,firstName','--
out','/home/bitnami/apps/webapp/dist/server/prod/public/user-
details.csv']);

userDetailsChild.on('exit', function (code: any) {
  if (code != 0) {
    userDetailsChild.kill();
    callback(new Error(), null);
  } else {
    console.log('userDetailsChild process closed with code ' + code);
    userDetailsChild.kill();
  }
});
```

When I try to run the same code with server credentials on amazon WordPress ec2  instance on my server machine it fails with no error message.
Somewhere I have seen path variables set as process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'];
But didnt worked in my case.
Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

While I do not know why the command is failing, I do know that you appear to be ignoring the more than likely helpful information coming back to you via stderr. ;)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response.you were right using stderr solved my problem. thanks!!